# Mockito - Null Pointer Exception

Tags: unit-testing, null, mockito

I have a stupidly simple class (right now) that just takes an Id and passes that along to the DAO.

```
@Service
public class AdHocReportServiceImpl {

    @Autowired
    private AdHocReportServiceImpl adHocReportDao;

    public List<AdHocReportResponseDto> getAdHocReportResults(String reportId) {
        return adHocReportDao.getAdHocReportResults(reportId);
    }
}
```

And I'm attempting to use Mockito to just verify that the logic is there (this app has no code coverage and I'm trying to change that a bit)

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class AdHocReportServiceTest {

@InjectMocks
private AdHocReportServiceImpl adHocReportServiceImpl = new AdHocReportServiceImpl();

@Mock
private AdHocReportDao adHocReportDao;

@Test
public void getAdHocReportResultsTest() {
    List<AdHocReportResponseDto> adHocReportResponseDtoList = new ArrayList<AdHocReportResponseDto>();
    AdHocReportResponseDto adHocReportResponseDto1 = new AdHocReportResponseDto();
    AdHocReportResponseDto adHocReportResponseDto2 = new AdHocReportResponseDto();

    adHocReportResponseDtoList.add(adHocReportResponseDto1);
    adHocReportResponseDtoList.add(adHocReportResponseDto2);

    when(adHocReportDao.getAdHocReportResults(anyString())).thenReturn(adHocReportResponseDtoList);
    adHocReportServiceImpl.getAdHocReportResults("anyString()");
}
}
```

Mockito is saying I'm getting getting a null pointer exception at adHocReportDao.  When I go to debug sure enough that DAO is null in the class that's being tested but I'm not sure what I could have done wrong and the Mockito documentation doesn't seem to be helping me out.  Thoughts?

Comment: I may be an idiot.  I think you've hit the nail on the head

Comment: Migrated comment to an answer. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Your `@Autowired` field is of type AdHockReportServiceImpl; if you want it to be injected using @InjectMocks you'll need to make it an AdHocReportDao like in your test.

Whether or not this is your root cause, this is one of the reasons that `@InjectMocks` is fragile and that you should probably prefer an explicit setter or a constructor for testing.